# Using synchronized in static variable

Tags: java, multithreading, static-variables

I have a static Map

```
private static Map<String, Car> cars = new HashMap<~>() //Map holding car objects
```

I use the variable inside a method like

```
private static String getCar(String name){
    return cars.get(name);
}
```

So, if I want to put lock on cars, is it fine to do like below for thread safety.

```
private static void xyz() {
    synchronized(cars) {
        Car c = getCar("abc");
        c.setColor("Green");
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Don't see why it isn't fine to do that

Comment: You might add a try/catch block around your return statement to catch NullPointerExceptions and return a non null result.

Comment: @JonLin I was confused because, the static variable cars is not directly accessed inside synchronized block.

Comment: @RusselShingleton Why would you try to catch a `NullPointerException` instead of checking for `null`s? It is so much more efficient to just use an `if` and avoid the NPE in the first place.

Comment: @RussellShingleton I will definitely do that, but I'm more concerned about the synchronized car variable and whether it will be locked or not?

Comment: @darkapple The cars monitor will be held until the thread exits the synchronized block, in this instance, not really any different than putting the block in `getCar(String)`.

Comment: @JonLin Since the method is used by others as well just to receive the information from the map and not making any modifications to the objects inside the object. So, I preferred to put synchronized block on the variable only. So, if the monitor for the variable cars is held, I can be confirmed that its quite thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's `synchronized` keyword can be applied to any object to "acquire a lock" on that object (or "synchronize on" that object) before proceeding. If any other process tries to run code that synchronizes on the same object at the same time, it will block until the process that locked the object exits the synchronized block.

The object you synchronize on does not have to be actually used in any part of the `synchronized` block; it could be a simple mutex object whose only purpose is to be locked and unlocked in synchronized blocks. However, it is important to note that simply synchronizing on an object **does not** prevent other threads from modifying it *if they do not also synchronize on that object*. It is a programmer/convention-enforced lock rather than a built-in lock, and all of your code that uses a shared object must "agree" to synchronize on it.

For example, with the code you wrote above, even though your `xyz()` method synchronizes on `cars`, you could write another method like this:

```
public void changeCar() {
    Car myCar = cars.get("abc");
    myCar.setColor("Blue");
}
```

that modifies `cars` *without* calling `synchronized`. It would be possible for this method to modify the "abc" car at the same time as your method `xyz()` is modifying it (i.e. violate thread safety) because it does not contain any code that invokes `synchronized` on `cars`.

If you want to ensure that your `cars` map is thread-safe (i.e. never modified by two methods concurrently), you must either

1. Ensure that any code that modifies `cars` first calls `synchronized(cars)`
2. Use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), which guarantees that put and get operations on it are thread-safe.

Comment: I'm confused with this line " However, it is important to note that simply synchronizing on an object does not prevent other threads from modifying it if they do not also synchronize on that object."

Comment: That means that calling `synchronized(cars)` in your method does not magically prevent any other method from modifying cars. It does prevent multiple calls to the `xyz()` method from executing concurrently, but it would not prevent a method like the `changeCar()` method I wrote from executing concurrently with `xyz()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine but do **take note** that with your current code you're not completely put lock on the cars object, **you can still access the cars in other method and set attributes *unless you  synchronized again on cars object***.

```
public static void otherMethod() {
  synchronized(cars) {
     Car myCar = cars.get("abc");
     myCar.setColor("Red");
  }
}
```

But if method xyz() is the **only place** you set attributes, then your code is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only worried about individual method synchronization, use

```
Map<String, Car> synchronizedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
```

This will automatically add synchronization to all the methods in the map, and make each method call atomic.  This is the map you should probably expose to your threads.

However, if you need to synchronize across multiple method calls (such a get followed by a put if something is null), your above approach would be needed.

Beware that the Car object needs to also be threadsafe as well, and without seeing that method, i can't say if it is or isn't.